# Integrating Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, svelte, sveltekit

I am trying to integrate a google map in my Svelte app.

I created a component with this for my JS:

```js
import {Loader} from '@googlemaps/js-api-loader';

let mapElement;

onMount(async () => {
    let loader = new Loader({
        apiKey: getConfig().GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY,
        version: 'weekly'
    });

    await loader.load();

    let {Map} = await google.maps.importLibrary('maps');

    let map = new Map(mapElement, {
        center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
        zoom: 8
    });
})
```

The inner html seems to load, and I have a grey area, but I do not have the map.

I checked most things:

- API key is fine
- HTML element is properly binded to `mapElement`
- HTML element has a fixed height

There is no error message in vite nor in the console. Any idea what could cause that or how I could debug this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the source of the problem, it was not an easy one.

I use mirage and I load it from `+layout.js` with:

```js
import {createMyMirageServer} from '$lib/mirage';

if (import.meta.env.DEV) {
    createMyMirageServer();
}
```

And I have this for the server creation:

```js
import {createServer, Model, Response} from 'miragejs';

export let createMyMirageServer = () => createServer({
    models: {
        user: Model
    },
    routes() {
        this.namespace = '/v1/api/app';

        this.post(
            '/users/signup/one',
            (schema, request) => {
                let headers = {}
                let data = {
                    auth_token: 'this.is.a.fake.token'
                }
                return new Response(200, headers, data);
            },
            {timing: 1000}
        );

        // A few other routes
    }
});
```

The mirage server prevents Google Maps from properly loading. If I comment the `createMyMirageServer()` instruction, it works fine.

I don't know why this is happening or how to solve this. I have asked the question on the mirage discord server, but if anyone has any clue, please write.

---

EDIT:

I had a reply from the mirage discord and it happens that Miragejs, by default, is blocking all requests, except the explicitly defined routes.

You can set up the [passthrough option](https://miragejs.com/api/classes/server/#passthrough). However, it has to be done manually for other origin hosts. I might look at Google Maps required hosts.

I am not a fan of this design though and I created [an issue](https://github.com/miragejs/miragejs/issues/1092) about it.

---

EDIT2 : I managed to have Miragejs and Google Maps adding :

```js
this.passthrough('https://maps.googleapis.com/**');
```

At the end of the `routes()` function.